# Nodejs web scraping with 3 requests inside 3 loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, node-modules

I have a task to web scrape a website category content and make it a json file. which I only can hardcode the homepage URL. Each category use ajax and each category has more than one page.

1. I should request the homepage url (ex: http://www.example.com/category.php , get how many category and save the category title
2. When I got the total category I will use **for loop** to request from (ex: http://www.example.com/category.php?category=i)
3. When I access each category, I should do request to count how many page in each category and use **for loop** (ex: http://www.example.com/category.php?category=i&page=x)
4. When I access each pages, I should count how many content in it and use **for loop** to get the data and saved it in the variable
5. I should generate a JSON file to save the result.

What is the node.js code structure to generate 3 requests inside 3 loops?

Comment: @RobertColumbia What is the code to do request inside loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Async waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall).

Example snippet:

```js
async.waterfall([
    firstFunction,
    secondFunction,
    lastFunction,
], (err, result) => {
    if(err){}
    
});
function firstFunction(callback) {
    callback(null);
}
function secondFunction(callback) {
    callback(null);
}
function lastFunction(callback) {
    callback(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to do a request inside a loop won't be any different than outside of one, the only big difference is going to be how it can be handled. With a single request of course you can generally write a simple function to do it all, but for something like this you'd be better off doing something like so:

- Create a single async function for each separate portion that may be useful somewhere else later (say, another project) such as: scraping the list of categories, scraping the list of pages in each category, and scraping the actual pages from the list in each category.
- Where it comes to using loops create an array for requests and another for responses, or use `map` or another loop to do this with a single variable, **but** instead of awaiting each request instead don't `await` any and just map request -> `Promise(response)`. After the map/whatever loop use `await Promise.all(arrayOfResponses)` to wait for all the requests to finish (which of course you can limit to only a part of the requests to keep it from getting you temporarily IP banned, or bringing down the site if it's server is weak).

By the time you get through one function like this others will be far easier. You could even write a general function that could be used for all of the requests and then just call that as needed and await it anywhere you like outside the function (so it's useful both for single requests and arrays).

An important part of making a bot though is to also try to be nice about it so you don't get in trouble. Part of this is considering the site and it's bandwidth so you don't bring it down as mentioned above, but you may also want to keep your personal account on the site (if any) from getting punished because of your bot.

Something that can somewhat help with this is setting a proper useragent which http://www.user-agents.org can be a good inspiration for. Notice how many include a product name, version, and website, and some also include an email address to contact the bots handler(s). These help identify the bot and if it's going haywire give them someone to contact rather than just immediately banning the useragent or IP address(es).